# Mysql sort and then insert

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables identical to these

```
date_base               date_search                   fecha_finish
-------------         ---------------                ----------------
id_fechab int         id_fechae  int                  id_fechar    int
fechab    datetime    fechae     datatime             fechar       datetime
```

The base date has records from 1 to 10 complete, and the search date only has 7, what does it do is show the dates in which the database does not have a search, if you understand me?

Example

```
date_base

2018-03-01 00:10:00
2018-03-01 00:15:00
2018-03-01 00:20:00
2018-03-01 00:25:00
2018-03-01 00:30:00
2018-03-01 00:35:00
2018-03-01 00:40:00
2018-03-01 00:45:00
2018-03-01 00:50:00
2018-03-01 00:55:00
```

It only has 7 dates

```
date_search 

    2018-03-01 00:10:00
    2018-03-01 00:15:00
    2018-03-01 00:20:00
    2018-03-01 00:25:00
    2018-03-01 00:30:00
    2018-03-01 00:35:00
    2018-03-01 00:40:00
```

what I want to do is that the date searched insert those 7 values and insert the 3 that do not find

this mysql compares to me what dates are not in this case will be 3 I want those 3 insert in the result date along with the missing ones, if you understand me

```
select * from fechap_b a left join fechap_c b on b.fechac_compara = a.fechap_base where b.fechac_compara is null
```

Result date has to be like this

```
fecha_result

2018-03-01 00:10:00
    2018-03-01 00:15:00
    2018-03-01 00:20:00
    2018-03-01 00:25:00
    2018-03-01 00:30:00
    2018-03-01 00:35:00
    2018-03-01 00:40:00
    2018-03-01 00:45:00
    2018-03-01 00:50:00
    2018-03-01 00:55:00
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you.

Comment: If dates is indexed, just tell the insert to ignore duplicate values